# Can't install vt-x haxm for Android studio 1.0.1 on Windows 8.1 (after trying google solutions)

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualization, haxm

I can't install haxm that is required for vt-x to run Android emulator in Android studio.
I enabled **Virtualization Technology** on BIOS, after it I enabled **Hyper-V** in windows features. When trying to install the Intel [HAXM](https://software.intel.com/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) I got message that my laptop doesn't support vt-x technology. But it suppose to according to this:
[Intel ARK](http://ark.intel.com/products/52220/Intel-Core-i3-2310M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_10-GHz)

After disabling **Hyper-V** in windows features I got message that my computer is supporting the vt-x but it is not enabled.

My laptop is:

- HP pavilion g6
- Windows 8.1 x64
- Processor: i3 2310m

P.S. I saw that HP laptops has problem with this issue but I hope someone can help me.

Comment: After struggling with my laptop I gave up. There is other option to run Android emulator in Android studio - via arm. But this way it's much more slower.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps

- Disable **Hyper-V** as it is not necessary.
- Go to **BIOS** setup and enable **Virtualization**.
- Disable Avast if you have.
- Install [HAXM](https://software.intel.com/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager). It should be installed sucessfully.

P.S. I am using HP laptop and have no problem with this issue.

Comment: This is the problem: after enabling the Virtualization in BIOS it still has problem to be installed.

Answer (score 2):

If you still have the problem and have avast:
after the steps given by mohit Singh, be aware that you need to restart your computer after desactivating avast or disable the "hardware virtualization" under settings for the changes to take effect. Sounds stupid but it can help people.